# System Freezes upon Running this code

Tags: java, linux, graphics

I'm following a Java game programming series on youtube, and all have been going well until we add some code to the program. The code for the program is:

```
package com.fagyapong.rain;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -247215114548172830L;

    public static int width = 300;
    public static int height = width / 16 * 9;
    public static int scale = 3;

    private JFrame frame;
    public Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    public Game() {

        // Setup Game window
        Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
        setPreferredSize(size);

        frame = new JFrame();
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {

        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        while (running) {
            update();
            render();
        }
    }

    public void update() {

    }

    public void render() {

        // Get the canvas' BufferStragy object
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();

        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Game game = new Game();
        game.frame.setResizable(false);
        game.frame.setTitle("Rain");
        game.frame.add(game);
        game.frame.pack();
        game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        game.frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();
    }
}
```

Below is code that causes the system freeze(it has been commented out in the above code)

```
Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
g.dispose();
bs.show();
```

Comment: It doesn't freeze the system for me. What happens for you exactly?

Comment: The program runs and display a window, but the system becomes unresponsive afterwards

Comment: Does it peak memory usage?

Comment: I think that is what it does because the system becomes completely unresponsive

Comment: Why don't you use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the problem a bit. I was having the same issue. The issue for me was the triple buffering. Instead, set the code to:

```
createBufferStrategy(2);
```

That way it's only double buffering. I don't have a fantastic computer, so I had to set it to 1 instead of 2. At that point, my guess is that it's not buffering at all. This is how I got it to work though.